# How to add "orderd data" wity apply method in pandas (not use for-loop)

Tags: python, pandas, apply

| ID | A | B | C | D | Orderd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No1 | 8 | 9 | 5 | 2 | D:2 C:5 A:8 B:9 |
| No2 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 9 | B:1 A:3 C:7 D:9 |
| No3 | 29 | 34 | 5 | 294 | C:5 A:29 B:34 D:294 |

I would like to add "Orderd" column with column of A, B, C and D.

If I use *for loop*, I can do it as like

```
for n in range(len(df)):
    df['Orderd'][n] = df.T.sort_values(by=n,ascending=True)[n].to_string()
```

However, this method is too slow. I would like to do like this with "**df.apply**" method for doing speedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use apply directly on your dataframe, indicating the axis = 1

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ["ID","A","B","C","D"]
data = [["No1",8,9,5,2],
        ["No2",3,1,7,9],
        ["No3",29,34,5,294]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df = df.set_index("ID") # important to avoid having an error

df["Orderd"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().to_dict(), axis=1)
```

outputs:

```
   A   B   C   D   Orderd
ID                  
No1     8   9   5   2   {'D': 2, 'C': 5, 'A': 8, 'B': 9}
No2     3   1   7   9   {'B': 1, 'A': 3, 'C': 7, 'D': 9}
No3     29  34  5   294     {'C': 5, 'A': 29, 'B': 34, 'D': 294}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
df['Ordered'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' '.join([':'.join(s) for s in dict(row[1:].sort_values().astype('str')).items()]), axis=1)
```

Basically, I take all values in the row excluding the first one, which gives you a series. I sort it and convert to string.Then I convert the series to an dict and retrieve the items. I then use two list comprehensions to first join the Letter-Value pairs with a colon and then join the pair strings with a space.